# Non UI thread modifying UI component

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread that needs to be receiving data all the time from the network and I want this data to be displayed to an EditText object.

Obviously, I can't access the UI EditText from within my receiving thread; what I read is that I can use AsyncTask but reading the example in [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html) it seems to me that I have to be done with receiving the data before I can be able to post the results to the UI component.

I can't use post or postDelayed as both will be run over the UI thread and I can't block the UI to receive the data; I need to keep receiving the data all the time.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalBroadcastManager, your Activity containing TextView will start listening for broadcast:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra("actionType");
            if(action.equals("updateTextView")){
                mTextView.setText("whatever you want to set");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Start listening, you can put it on onResume too
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName()));
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something);
    }
}
```

So whenever your Thread receive something that needs to update the screen, call this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName());
intent.putExtra("actionType", "updateTextView");

// Once this is called, your broadcast receiver in MyActivity should receive it and start processing
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also remember to unregister it in onDestroy or onPause.

*side note: you need to import android support v4 library, and you can pass simple String or object over by intent using Intent.putExtra("","") and Inteng.getExtra("");

Comment: I know my question is stupid, but how can I access my UI components in the onReceive method?

Comment: Well no question is stupid. Generally you will have some class variable declared in your MyActivity class. I'll edit that first portion of code.

Comment: It works :) Please let me try to understand what happened here:
We're basically broadcasting the data we are receiving from one thread to the whole process so any broadcast listener within this process will catch it using intent; right?

Comment: Exactly, but you see when we declare an Intent to broadcast, we name it as `MyActivity.class.getSimpleName()`, it means only Activities which register using `new IntentFilter(MyActivity.class.getSimpleName())` will receive it, thus filtering is important to capture only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to implement a data listener interface.

```
public interface DataListener{
    void onUpdateData(MyData data);
}
```

You activities that contain the UI components that need to be updated will implement this interface. It will specify what need to do with updated data.
You may want to keep all instances these data listener interface somewhere in your app.
I assume that you have a different thread to handle network sending/receiving actions. On receiving data, you just call:

```
dataListenerInstance.onUpdateData(data)
```

Then it will activate the handler that you have implemented in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity call AsyncTask but make @Override method onPostExecute(..)

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
          DownloadFileFromURL downloader = new DownloadFileFromURL(){
               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Integer file_content) {
                                    onCompleteLoad();
                                }
                            };
               downloader.execute(new String[]{file_url, fileName});

               ...
```

onCompleteLoad(); - will be call in UI thread of MainActivity. You don't need even implements Interface!

Secon way more suitable for server solutions, but can also be used on the client it is Callable

```
public class DoGetSize implements Callable<Integer> {
    private final String file_url;
    private int lenghtOfFile = -1;

    public DoGetSize(String file_url) {
        this.file_url = file_url;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(file_url);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lenghtOfFile;
    }
}
```

And call this like:

```
    FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask(new DoGetSize(file_url));
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    es.submit (task);
    try {
        Integer result = task.get();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.length() != result.intValue()) {
          // Do something
           ...
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can send and receive any object in such a way

Full example see on github: https://github.com/app-z/OffLineShop/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/appz/offlineshop/offlineshop/MainActivity.java

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using a simple delegation.

```
class NonUIThread { 
     private NonUIThreadDelegate delegate; //NonUIThreadDelegate can be an interface or an object that has access to your UI thread like an Activity

     public void setDelegate(NonUIThreadDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
     }

     private void doSomthing() { 
        //do something and at the end:
        delegate.someMethodThatUpdatesThatComponent();
     } 
 }
```

---

```
class TheUIThread implements NonUIThreadDelegate /*assuming you've decided to make NonUIThreadDelegate an interface*/ { // the "delegator"
    /*
    your code
    */

    private void initiateNonUIThread() {
        NonUIThread nonUIThread;
        /*do whatever needed*/
        nonUIThread.setDelegate(this);
        nonUIThread.start();
    }

    public void someMethodThatUpdatesThatComponent() { //will be called by the non ui thread
        //update the UI
    }   
 }
```

It's explained a little better (of course using AsincTask) in here: [Simple Delegation Pattern in Android](http://myexperienceproject.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/delegation-pattern.html)